# Send POST data via Menu yii2-admin

Tags: php, post, yii2

I'm using yii2-admin by mdmsoft. I have made a menu named Logout. For it to work I need to send the request as POST. The convention is to use the linkOptions method. But how to use it here? The developer has given a data field for providing extra data with the menu. But how can I use it to send a POST request in order to logout of the application?

All the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you send the request with POST? You do not have to send any data to a logout link. Just change this silly behavior and make it work with GET. Another solution would be to make an AJAX post request when you press the link instead of following the link, but really... change the logout function to accept GET.

Comment: I cant. I'm using a library. To make it to use GET, I'll have to make a hell lot of changes. The quickest way to do it is by POST.  When I wasn't using yii2-admin, I was able to achieve the required task. Also, I need yii2-admin, so can't just really remove it from the project. [Yii2-Admin](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin)